# How to get all page pagination data using curl in php

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I have implemented one data scraping script which fetch data using CURL.

But that fetch record only one page but i want all data because on that page pagination is there.

We are getting data using

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath_resultset =  $xpath->query("//div[@class='parentListing']");
```

in above code parentListing is div class and i am fetching record between div and grep the data using different different class.

Can any one have idea how to get pagination data of all page.

If any one have any suggestion then please help me.

Thanks...

Comment: There's usually a 'next' link. Just follow that until there isn't one anymore.

Comment: hi i need example of pagination so can understand and give me some reference or code for that...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no generic pagination type. You should know pagination element div,ul,li or its name,class name etc. And then you can access pagination links, and sends requests to this links

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath_resultset =  $xpath->query("//div[@class='parentListing']/a");
```

Otherwise you must walk all dom and decide which element can be paginate element. Some pages adds next and previous meta links. You can search these tags :

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$next_resultset =  $xpath->query("//link[@rel='next']");
$prev_resultset =  $xpath->query("//link[@rel='prev']");
```